# Extract Data from Excel Cell to PowerPoint Shape with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an excel workbook with the julian day in column one, the normal high temperature in column two, and the normal low temperature in column three. I need to write a script in PowerPoint VBA to match the current Julian Day with the same number in Column one in the workbook. Then I need it to extract the normal high for that day (Column two) and insert that number into a named shape in a particular PPT slide. Here is what I have so far:

```
Function SectionIndexOf(sSectionName As String) As Long
'This Function makes sure you can declare the name of any Section Name
'in the Sub below.

    Dim x As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For x = 1 To .Count
            If .Name(x) = sSectionName Then
                SectionIndexOf = x
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function

Sub Climo()

Headlines = SectionIndexOf("Headlines")

'Open the Excel Workbook.
Dim CLI As New Excel.Workbook
Set CLI = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("Z:\climo.xlsx")

'Grab the first Worksheet in the Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim NormalHi As String
Dim NormalLo As String
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide

Set WS = CLI.Worksheets(1)

Dim i As Long
'Loop through all rows in Column A (Julian Day)

For i = 1 To WS.Range("A372").End(xlUp).Row
    NormalHi = WS.Cells(i, 9).Value
    Debug.Print NormalHi 'This just returns new blank lines

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If sld.sectionIndex = Headlines Then
                With sld.Shapes("NormalHi")
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = Arial
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbRed
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = NormalHi
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Before even trying to figure out how to match the current Julian Day with the proper row in the Excel workbook, I am just trying to extract data from any cell and plot it in the shape. I get no errors when I run this and using Debug.Print gives me blank new lines. Not sure what is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in your question that the Normal High data is found in column 2 but then when you are grabbing the value, you're referencing column 9. Perhaps that's the issue?

`NormalHi = WS.Cells(i, 9).Value`

Comment: ha wow. For some reason I thought that was the Row and not the Column. Thanks!